# javascript getattribute method with regex

Tags: javascript, regex, getattribute

```
<div id="foo" platform="bar" table-index="1">
  hello!
</div>
```

if i use getAttribute method and get value, it'll be like this

```
var ele = document.querySelector("#foo").getAttribute("platform")
```

and i can get "bar" by ele variable.

but i wanna use getAttribute with regular expression.

```
var ele = document.querySelector("#foo").getAttribute(`regex contains just "index"`)
```

word "table-index" end with index. so i wanna find attribute and get 1(table-index value) just use "index" and regex.

i have no idea way to use regex in attiributeName.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`getAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute) cannot be used in this manner-- it accepts a string for an argument, not a regex.  However, you could implement a way of doing something similar.  The below approach works by using the [`attributes`] property of an element and then iterating over them, searching for one that is matched by the regex, and then returning that value.

Note that this particular implementation naively assumes that you are using a regex that will match only a single attribute on the element and will return the first match it encounters-- however, you could be more clever and write something more robust that returns an array of matched attribute/value pairs.

```js
function getAttributeByRegex(element, regex) {
  const attributes = element.attributes;
  for (let i = attributes.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    const attr = attributes[i];
    if (regex.test(attr.name)) {
      return attr.value;
    }
    return undefined;
  }  
}

const value = getAttributeByRegex(
  document.querySelector('#foo'),
  /-index/
);

console.log(value);
```

```html
<div id="foo" platform="bar" table-index="1">
  hello!
</div>
```

Comment: thanks a lot! your example works perfectly and helped me making js funciton.

Comment: Glad it helped!  Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

You will have to iterate through the attributes to find the attribute with the name that matches your RegExp.

```js
function regexMatch(element, regex) {
  let match = [...element.attributes].find(i => regex.test(i.name));
  if (!match) return undefined;
  return match.value;
}

let ele = regexMatch(document.querySelector("#foo"), /index/g);
console.log(ele);
```

```html
<div id="foo" platform="bar" table-index="1">
  hello!
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const match = findAttributeMatch("foo", "index");
console.log(document.querySelector('#foo').getAttribute(match));

function findAttributeMatch(id, attribute) {
  const regex = RegExp(`(${attribute})`, 'gm');
  const element = document.querySelector(`#${id}`);

  const a = [...element.attributes].find(node => regex.test(node.name));
  return a && a["name"];
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<div id="foo" platform="bar" table-index="1">
  hello!
</div>
```